# Google Datastore - Problems updating entity

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I am dusting off my google app-engine / datastore skills ... and getting stuck on something very simple.

As per [the example on the GAE documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Updating_an_Object) I am trying to update an entity as follows:

```
// persistence and business logic
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

// get it
NickName n = pm.getObjectById(NickName.class, nicknameId);

// update fields
n.givenName = "new name";
n.nickName = "new nickname";
n.timeStamp = new Date();               

// close manager to persist changes
pm.close();
```

This doesn't work (as in the changes are not persisted, but no errors or anything else)!

At the same time I found that if I create a new entity with the same ID the changes get persisted:

```
// persistence and business logic
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

NickName n = new NickName("new name", "new nickname", new Date());

// set id
n.id = nicknameId;

pm.makePersistent(n);

pm.close();
```

I have the feeling I already solved this the 1st time I approached app engine and the data-store.

This is what my entity looks like:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class NickName {

    public NickName(String name, String nickname, Date timestamp) {
        this.givenName = name;
        this.nickName = nickname;
        this.timeStamp = timestamp;
    }

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    public String id;

    @Persistent
    public String givenName;

    @Persistent
    public String nickName;

    @Persistent
    public Date timeStamp;
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: "This doesn't work!" is not a good statement. What is the exact error you see in console logs?

Comment: I see nothing in the console log - everything seems fine but the changes are not persisted when I look at the datastore (or try to pull the entity out, the old values are still there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue may be that you are setting the fields directly instead of going through the setter methods.  I'm fairly certain that JDO works by instrumenting the field setters so that they notify the persistence layer of any changes that occur.  It has no way of directly monitoring changes to the backing field values themselves.  So maybe try:

```
n.setGivenName("new name");
n.setNickName("new nickname");
n.setTimeStamp(new Date());
```

You're able to get away with setting the field directly when you create the object because the `makePersistent()` call tells the persistence manager that is needs to inspect the field values and save them.  Though it's worth noting that setting field values directly like this is generally considered to be poor coding style.

Also, have you tried using the JPA interface instead of the JDO interface?  In GAE they should be interchangeable:

```
EntityManager em = EMF.get();

NickName n = em.find(NickName.class, nicknameId);

n.givenName = "new name";
n.nickName = "new nickname";
n.timeStamp = new Date();    

em.merge(n);

em.close();
```

This gives you an explicit `merge()` call which should work even with setting the field values directly.

Comment: FYI The JDO way of monitoring changes to *public* fields directly is to mark the calling class as @PersistenceAware. JPA on the other hand has no such way, so best to stick to JDO

Comment: I will give this a shot asap. I was lazy and didn't put any setters since it was just a test - thanks for the great suggestion

Comment: @DataNucleus - The choice between JPA and JDO is really a matter of personal preference.  Personally I feel that JDO is a fairly poor option, but to each his own.  In any case, I don't think the ability to monitor changes made directly to public fields is a compelling reason to choose JDO.  In a well designed app, you don't generally have or set public fields in the first place.

Comment: Personal preference ? Sure, apart from the fact that JPA has no fetch groups, datastore txns, specification of indexes, and many other things.

Comment: @DataNucleus - JPA's fetch group equivalent is FetchType.EAGER.  It absolutely supports transactions.  You're correct that it can't specify indexes, but in most serious production environments you would not generate your schema or your indexes in your ORM classes/mappings anyways.  So yes, personal preference.  Both solutions are used quite successfully in a wide range of projects.  But something makes me suspect that you may not be speaking from an entirely neutral point of view.

Comment: Understand what a fetch group is ... JPA has "default fetch group" only ... you cannot absolutely configure fetch groups at runtime (why do you think it is listed as a possible item in JPA2.1?). I said "datastore transactions", and that means locking (as opposed to optimistic checks) ... and that is only in JPA2 (GAE uses JPA1). I implement JDO and JPA actually, both to the specs, so please don't try to imply that I speak from a point of view of bias.

Comment: @DataNucleus - Having a default fetch group is quite different than having "no fetch groups".  One fetch group is enough for handling most common use-cases.  For most developers, transactions mean two things; atomicity and rollback, which JPA transactions provide.  With many projects the feature set provided by JPA is entirely sufficient, so I wouldn't say that JDO is uncategorically better than JPA just because it provides features that most people don't need most of the time.  If you need those features, use JDO, if not then pick your preference.

Comment: And one other point with respect to GAE; it only uses optimistic transactions.  So in this context, support for other transaction styles is moot.